# Sass animation puzzle: Make the rings fat to start, then thin out as they expand

Tags: css, animation, sass

**Goal**

To make a monotone big bang-y, black hole-y, heart beat-y type of animation. It explodes then sucks back in then goes to an infinite pulsating heart beat like loop. It's a CSS animation project I'm making for myself.

1. Explode (Semi-done)

   - It needs to expand off screen without scroll bar madness
   - It should start with a solid expanding larger inner circle with a small hole in the center
   - The outer rings should expand from the outside of the inner circle
   - The rings should start fat, then thin out as they expand
2. Suck in (Done)

   - This should happen very quickly
   - The animation should "bounce"
3. Heart beat loop (To-Do)

   - The pulse should start from the middle and expand in quick succession outwards
   - It's a heart beat, so two pulses, then a pause.

I suck at math and I'm new to Sass and programming. I don't intend to have someone finish this but it would be interesting to see how others would go about this task. Basically I need help with a couple of problems I'm stuck on.

Here's what I have:

```
body
    background-color: black
    margin: 0

/* Get it all in the center */
.container
    display: flex
    width: 100vw
    height: 100vh
    align-items: center
    justify-content: center
    vertical-align: 50%

/* Here's the animation for the first inner circle. It's outside of the loop because it doesn't follow the same pattern */
.donut
    display: inline-block
    position: fixed
    border-radius: 50%
    visibility: hidden
    transform: scale(50%)

@keyframes donut_1
        0%
            transform: scale(0%)
        0.01%
            transform: scale(4em)
        95%
            transform: scale(150%)
        100%
            transform: scale(40%)
            visibility: visible

.donut:nth-child(1)
    border: 2.75em solid #eee
    width: 1em
    height: 1em
    animation: donut_1 6.6s cubic-bezier(.23,.74,.74,1.2) 0.8s 1 forwards

/* Setting up the variables: */

/* b = border width */
/* s = size (width and height of the circle) */
/* d = amount of donuts */
/* ti = animation timing */
/* de = delay start */

$b: 2
$s: 7
$d: 24
$ti: 4
$de: 4.3
$c: 10

@for $i from 2 through $d
    @keyframes donut_#{$i}
        0%
            transform: scale(0%)
        .01%
            transform: scale(10%) 
            /* this is my effort to start animating from outside of the inner circle this doesn't seem to work... */
            border: #{$b * 2}em solid #eee
            /* my botched effort to start with fat rings */
        80%
            transform: scale(120%)
            visibility: visible
            border: #{$b}em solid #eee
            /* then to have them thin out as they expand */
        100%
            transform: scale(40%)
            visibility: visible

@for $i from 2 through $d
    .donut:nth-child(#{$i})
        animation: donut_#{$i} #{$ti}s cubic-bezier(.24,.79,.46,1.46) #{$de}s 1 forwards
        border: #{$b}em solid #eee
        width: #{$s}em
        height: #{$s}em
        $b: $b - 0.1
        $s: $s + 5
        $de: $de - .18
        $ti: $ti + .2
```

And here's the HTML - very simple! Thanks :nth-child!

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="donut"></div>
    <div class="donut"></div>
    <div class="donut"></div>
    <div class="donut"></div>
    <div class="donut"></div>
    <div class="donut"></div>
    <div class="donut"></div>
    <div class="donut"></div>
    <div class="donut"></div>
    <div class="donut"></div>
    <div class="donut"></div>
    <div class="donut"></div>
    <div class="donut"></div>
    <div class="donut"></div>
    <div class="donut"></div>
    <div class="donut"></div>
    <div class="donut"></div>
    <div class="donut"></div>
    <div class="donut"></div>
    <div class="donut"></div>
    <div class="donut"></div>
    <div class="donut"></div>
    <div class="donut"></div>
    <div class="donut"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

So two big blockades.

I can't figure out how to start the outer rings to start expanding from a fixed position outside of the inner circle. (I've commented in the code my failed effort)

I can't figure the math to start the rings fat then thin out when they expand. Right now, they start 'fattish' get larger, then thin out. I know this has to do with the scaling expansion but am having (two days now) difficulty figuring it out.

For some reason it doesn't work on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/aronikun/pen/wvdKMvm) but you can see a working version at [atomu.me](https://atomu.me).

I'm hoping someone out there can help a brother out!